# How to sell goods and services for ETH?

Tags: ether, markets

How does one sell their goods and services for ETH?

[Craigslist allows users to enable a 'cryptocurrency okay' notice](https://blockexplorer.com/news/craigslist-now-allows-specify-accept-cryptocurrency-payment/), but are there any other means to sell your goods (like eBay or Amazon third-party sellers) and services?

Should merchants make their own websites? Where is a registry for them?

Answer (score 2):

This will largely depend on how you interact with your client base. For example if you're using craigslist and doing in person transactions, you could simply get the person to send you Ethereum to your mobile wallet or other Ethereum wallet instead of taking cash.

Purse.io is a way of buying amazon products with Bitcoin via a direct person-to-person transaction hosted through Purse.io

- https://purse.io

If you're using wordpress here's an article on accepting Bitcoin but it can be adapted for Ethereum.

- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/bitcoin-plugins/